# Use Https for integrating and then using library with android app

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am integrating the JEELIZ face filter library with the android app. the requirement in its [documentation](https://github.com/jeeliz/jeelizGlassesVTOWidget)[https://github.com/jeeliz/jeelizGlassesVTOWidget] says that you must have an Https connection to use this library. I don't know without a website how https is used. I am using an android web view for integrating it with my app.

I am using web service here in a .java file and I am using the library( Weblink to the library's source code) in .html file given below

```
package com.asad.webview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
      <title>VTO Widget Amazon</title>
      <script src="https://appstatic.jeeliz.com/jeewidget/JeelizNNCwidget.js"></script>
      <script>
         function startWidget() {
           JEEWIDGET.start({
             sku: 'blaze_round_or_bleudegrademiroir',
             searchImageMask: 'https://appstatic.jeeliz.com/jeewidget/images/target.png',
             searchImageColor: 0xFF0000
            })
          }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="JeeWidget">
         <canvas id="JeeWidgetCanvas"></canvas>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#JeeWidget {
    width: 800px!important;
    height: 450px!important;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 20px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
```

And the XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

And on running this no content is getting shown.
How to use HTTPS for running this library?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun actual use of API is not getting used because according to API pre conditions it need HTTPS. And I am not getting understand that how I integrate HTTPS with an android app.

Comment: Host your HTML file then request your HTML file from the link.